# (SVG) Transform origin of grouped path element is not getting applied

Tags: svg, attributes, tags, transform, transformation

I want to define grouped shapes in the `<def>` section and display them via the `<use>` tag with the `transformation-origin` being the group's center. Following is a minimal example illustrating my issue:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
<defs>
    <g id="triangle">
        <path fill="green" d="m 24 0 l 24 41.569 l -48 0 z" />
        <circle cx="24" cy="24" r="1" fill="red" />
        <rect width="48" height="41.569" fill="purple" fill-opacity="20%" />
    </g>
</defs>
<rect width="100" height="100" />
<rect fill="gray" x="100" width="100" height="100" />
<rect width="100" height="100" />
<rect fill="gray" y="100" width="100" height="100" />
<rect width="100" height="100" x="100" y="100" />
<use href="#triangle" transform-origin="50% 50%" transform="translate(100 100)"  />
</svg>
```

As it is my understanding, the triangle should be centered in the background. But in actuality, the top left corner of the group is centered.

I have tested my example against the [MDN transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform-origin) one. The MDN one works well in the same environment (Edge Browser & VSCode). This lets me believe I am missing some side effects of the used tags or attributes

- [Observed behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daiou.png)
- [Expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLPFR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A scale transform has a centre point i.e. a point that doesn't change position.
- So does a rotation - there's a centre of rotation.
- A translate transform does not, every location moves. There's therefore no origin so transform-origin does nothing.